# Arrow function confusion

Tags: javascript

I was doing a question on codesignal and when I couldn't get the answer myself for all tests, revealed the answers and saw this one; while I understand what it's trying to do (make sure positions are not divisible by n, and if it is increment n by one) I'm having trouble understanding the arrow function syntax and, rewriting it myself from their code.

```
function obst(inputArray) {
for (var n=1;;n+=1) if(inputArray.every(x=>x%n)) return n;}
```

Comment: it basically says "for each x, return x%n", modifying the response. read more about it at the spec - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want help on how to write this as an arrow function?

Comment: The title of your question is very similar to one of the **bad** examples on the [ask] page.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, every function written like this:

```
function(args) {
   // DO SOME STUFF
}
```

can be written like this:

```
(args) => {// DO SOME STUFF}
```

In your case, the method .every() expects a function, and

```
function(x) {
    return x%n;
}
```

is written as

```
x => x%n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputArray.every(x=>x%n)
```

is the same as

```
inputArray.every(function (x){
  return x%n
}))
```

( except for the way the 'this' keyword works )

Answer (score 0):

For any doubt about Javascript language, i recommend the [You Dont Know Js series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)
written by Kyle Simpson.

It's a very enlightening book.

**Tip**: When you write a code, ask question to youself like:

- what i'm doing?
- assigment means equality?
- what are the methods that can i use in string variables?

And something like that.

Stimulate yourself to know what in the actual fudge, you are doing.

Cheers!.